# JPA Specification - create query using nested field splitted into two database column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I wanna build a query using criteria builder which will allow me to fetch records where the value of nested field member is greater that given amount.

```java
//jpa annotations
abstract class SomeAbstractClass{

  public abstract SomeAbstractNestedClass getSomeAbstractNestedClass();
}
```

```java
//jpa annotations
class ConcreteClass extends SomeAbstractClass {

  private ConcreteNestedClass concreteNestedClass;

  @Override
  public SomeAbstractNestedClass getSomeAbstractNestedClass() {
    return concreteNestedClass;
  }

}
```

```java
//jpa annotations
@TypeDef(name = "MoneyAmountWithCurrencyType", typeClass = PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency.class)
abstract class SomeAbstractNestedClass {

  @Columns(columns = {
      @Column(name = "money_currency"),
      @Column(name = "money_number")})
  @Type(type = "MoneyAmountWithCurrencyType")
 private Money money;

}
```

```java
class ConcreteNestedClass extends SomeAbstractNestedClass {}
```

```java
public Specification<SomeAbstractClass> getSpecification(QueryDto dto) {

  return (Root<SomeAbstractClass> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

    Root<ConcreteClass> concreteClass = cb.treat(root, ConcreteClass.class);

    Join<ConcreteClass, ConcreteNestedClass> joinedNested = concreteClass.join("concreteNestedClass", JoinType.LEFT); //SingularAttributeJoin

    //second get call causes mentioned exception
    //after first call returned attribue is SingularAttributePath
    Path<BigDecimal> money = joinedNested.get("money").get("number");

    return cq.where(cb.greaterThan(money, dto.getSomeBigDecimal())).getRestriction();
  };
}
```

`Money` is an object which comes from `org.javamoney.moneta` package and it holds two fields `currency` and `number`, both fields are stored into separate columns in the database (`money_currency` and `money_number`), what I want to achieve is just build some criteria queries using only `number` value and ignoring `currency`. I tried to build a query as above, but unfortunately, I'm getting an exception like below, any ideas on how I can deal with it?

In the place commented in code I'm getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal
>   attempt to dereference path source [null.money] of basic type; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to
>   dereference path source [null.money] of basic type

P.S Not sure if my inheritance hierarchy has something common with `Money` field.

Comment: If you want to access specific parts of `Money` in your query, then probably a custom `UserType` is not the best solution. An `@Embeddable` would be a better choice